# How to loop through a badly formed CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, .net-core

I have a CSV file I want to import into my DB, but it is not well formed. The problem for me is that I can loop through the field names easily, but when I get to the rows containing data, ie starting with a number I am getting confused as the columns extend to five columns from two and are noted through a number (there may be up to 48,000 rows per file containing data).

The `Some Field Name` rows are metadata, then when it gets to the first cell in a row being a number, this is actual data.

I use the following code to populate a list with all of the rows, regardless of how many columns there are in a row.

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileLocation));
List<string> listRows = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
   listRows.Add(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

I can deal with the `Some Field Name` columns because they are fixed names, I can do this by splitting the string, so I get my values.

What I am struggling to do, is when the first column changes to a number, is how to test that I am no longer reading the `Some Field Name` but that I am now reading a row with data that is denoted by the first cell in the row changing to a number (integer) from `Some Field Name`.

```
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
Some Field Name ,   Some Field Value    ,               ,           ,   
1               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:46:23    ,   0:00:00 ,   9
2               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:48:23    ,   0:02    ,   9
3               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:50:23    ,   0:04:00 ,   9
4               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:52:23    ,   0:06    ,   9
5               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:54:23    ,   0:08:00 ,   9
6               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:56:23    ,   0:10    ,   9
7               ,   04/12/2018          ,   11:58:23    ,   0:12:00 ,   9
8               ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:00:23    ,   0:14    ,   9
9               ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:02:23    ,   0:16:00 ,   9
10              ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:04:23    ,   0:18    ,   9
11              ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:06:23    ,   0:20:00 ,   9
12              ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:08:23    ,   0:22    ,   9
13              ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:10:23    ,   0:24:00 ,   9
14              ,   04/12/2018          ,   12:12:23    ,   0:26    ,   9
```

TIA

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for here. Surely you will just need to write some code that handles this strange format?

Comment: You do not have csv!!!  It is fixed width data.

Comment: You may use the CsvHelper nuget package (not sure its available for .net core). You can use that parser and specify `|` as field delimiter

Comment: I have removed | and replaced with a comma. I was previously told on here to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try following which is still removing the | instead of the updated comma :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FixedColumnWidth fixColumnWidth = new FixedColumnWidth();
            DataTable dt =  fixColumnWidth.ReadFile(FILENAME);
        }

    }
    public class FixedColumnWidth
    {
        public DataTable ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            string line = "";
            string pattern = @"^\d+$";

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));



            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    List<string> row = GetData(line);
                    Match match = Regex.Match(row[0].Trim(), pattern);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                            int.Parse(row[0]),
                            DateTime.Parse(row[1] + " " + row[2]),
                            row[3],
                            int.Parse(row[4])
                        }); 

                    }
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
        private List<string> GetData(string line)
        {
            int[] START_COLUMNS = { 0, 17, 41, 57, 69 };
            List<string> array = new List<string>();

            for (int startCol = 0; startCol < START_COLUMNS.Count(); startCol++)
            {
                if (startCol == START_COLUMNS.Count() - 1)
                {

                    array.Add(line.Substring(START_COLUMNS[startCol]).Trim());
                }
                else
                {

                    array.Add(line.Substring(START_COLUMNS[startCol], START_COLUMNS[startCol + 1] - START_COLUMNS[startCol]).Trim(new char[] { ',', ' '}));
                }

            }
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have asked the wrong question here, after playing with the code, I will change the question.

Comment: Post actual sample of text.  If you have more than one file post data before you merge the data.  Do not sort data being posted.  I've been parsing text files like this for over 40 years and you need to see samples of every thing to do it correctly.  I suspect you have a header in each file (and may be a header on each page of ~80 lines).  The data looks like an index in 1st column.  Then a DateTime which for some reason look reason is split in multiple columns.  Then last column a value.  Data looks like it is 40 years old and is output to a 120 column high speed printer.

Comment: I updated code to attempt to parse file.  Not sure what the fourth column contains so  I just made it a string.